# dart.sdkPath seems to not be working to override VS Code's usage of a Dart SDK that comes with my Flutter SDK

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, sdk

I had a problem of resloving dependencies due to null safety and I installed another dart version via choco, my system terminals see the new lower version 2.17.6 but the vscode terminal is seeing the dart sdk bundled version with flutter.

I tried adding it to the seetngs.JSON file 'dart.sdkPath": "C:/tools/dart-sdk/bin"' to indicate the newly downloaded dart sdk but it's not working. Please I need help

Comment: Try remove the bin part of your path. The variable name indicate path to the sdk itself and not just the binaries.

Answer (score 0):

You should just give the SDK path without the `/bin` part.

If you like reading source code, you can see this hinted at in https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/blob/master/src/extension/sdk/sdk_manager.ts in `searchForSdks`, and https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/blob/master/src/shared/constants.ts in `dartVMPath`.

As for why the extension uses your Flutter one instead of what you specified, the setting's description reads:

> The location of the Dart SDK to use for analyzing and executing code. If blank (or not a valid SDK), Dart Code will attempt to find it from the `PATH` environment variable. When editing a Flutter project, the version of Dart included in the Flutter SDK is used in preference.

I'd suggest you look into upgrading your Flutter SDK if you believe you have version-related feature-support issues instead of trying to mix Flutter / Dart SDKs.